# Klondike Solitaire - moving partial sequences between columns

Tags: solitaire, klondike-solitaire

You'd think all the rules for this game would be well established but I have a question about the movement of partial sequences between columns in the tableau. Lets say I have two columns with the values:
7C, 6H, 5C, 4D and 4H, 3C, 2D

I want to get the 4H and move it to a foundation pile so I take the 3C, 2D and move them onto the 4D of the first column. I've always played this way and I've yet to find a computer version that doesn't allow it but is that how it is supposed to work?

The Microsoft help says - *"You can also move sequentially organized runs of cards between columns. Just click the deepest card in the run and drag them all to another column."* So I have to wonder if *deepest* means you can only move the entire sequence or just the deepest desired card...

[Lady Cadogan's Illustrated Games of Solitaire or Patience](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/21642/21642-h/21642-h.htm#canfield) actually says *"If there be more than one card at the bottom of a row, all must be moved together or not at all."* (where row means column)

http://www.bicyclecards.com/card-games/rule/klondike says *"If more than one card is face up on a tableau pile, all such cards must be moved as a unit."*

[Solitaire and Patience By George Hapgood 1920](http://books.google.com/books?id=DS8VAAAAYAAJ) - *"Any number of cards, provided that they form a complete sequence of alternating colors, may be transferred to the opposite colored card of the next higher rank, but parts of sequences may not be moved."*

[Patience : a series of games with cards 3rd Edition by Ednah Dow Littlehale Cheney, Copyright 1894, Published 1895 by Lee and Shepard in Boston](https://openlibrary.org/works/OL15738025W/Patience)
Appears as Triangle but only allows one card to be moved at a time - "You cannot (as in Fooliana) change more than once card from one line to another at once;". This version of Triangle allows complete access to the stock. A 2 deck version appears under the name Staircase. Staircase allows any number of cards in a sequence to be moved. The 2nd edition in 1875 did not include Triangle. The 3rd edition notes that the previous edition contained only one game, Brunette and Blonde, that had an alternating color marriage rule.

Mary Whitmore Jones's third series of collected Patience games from 1894 says "a sequence of cards may be lifted bodily and transferred to where it fits".

[Games of Patience by Tarbart (1901)](http://books.google.com/books?id=GTEOAAAAYAAJ) states says about Demon (1 deck Klondike) "A sequence of cards may be played bodily at any time..." but says about Triangle (2 deck Klondike) "A sequence of cards, or any portion of a sequence, may be played bodily at any time..."

[Foster's Complete Hoyle - 1909](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL7004580M/Foster%27s_complete_Hoyle)
"If there is more than one card face up on any pile, they must be moved together or not at all."

[Hoyle's Games - 1914](http://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/011206253)
No partial movement - "In this game the player is not allowed to borrow a card from one file unless it is the only card on that file, face up, or unless he can take all the cards that are face up together."
This book claims that Klondike is the 4 pile version (now commonly known as Canfield or Demon) was the original form and what we know as Klondike is a simplified form which is called "Seven-Card Klondike" in this book.

Do you ever play where you can NOT move partial sequences around on the tableau? I know there are lots of variations - redeals, draw 3 vs 1, reuse foundation cards, etc but I haven't seen partial/full sequence movement categorized as a variation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is regarding the game that when played with 1 deck uses 7 build piles.

The earliest recorded rules for this game appear in two different books from 1894 both refer to the game as Triangle. In one version only a single card can be moved and in the other entire sequences may be moved. Partial sequence movement was first recorded in a 2 deck version named Triangle in 1901.

So in the span of 7 years 3 different variations of movement between the tableau or building piles were recorded.

From 1909 to at least 1920, after the game became known as Klondike or sometimes Canfield, the rules almost always required complete sequence movement when more than one face up card was present on the source pile.

At some point partial sequence movement became more common (at least in computer versions) and is allowed by Microsoft Solitaire. Very few computer versions can be found that have split-sequence/full-sequence as a variation, one example is http://www.solitairecity.com/Klondike_Rules.shtml.

Answer (score 5):

I've never heard of any variation that would not allow you to do this. Though the help text you quoted is ambiguous, I believe that "deepest card" refers to the "deepest card that you want to move", not the "deepest card in the entire column". If the computer itself that has such a help file allows you to do the partial-run move anyway, do you have a reason for thinking that there is any such variation that doesn't allow it?

Comment: Lady Cadogan clearly states you have to move all cards at once, at least I can't read it any other way. Another old book, "The Official Rules of Card Games: Hoyle Up-to-date By U.S. Playing Card Co" uses the same wording as Cadogan.

Comment: Added another quote from the Hapgood book.

Comment: Most digital versions of the game not only allow for this but also tend to show how to do it in basic tutorials that they have.