# Canfield solitaire: moving partial sequences

Tags: solitaire

According to the [Wikipedia description of Canfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canfield_%28solitaire%29), "cards on the tableau are also moved one unit, provided that the entire column has to be moved". In other words, this suggests that if you move a sequence of cards from one column to another, that sequence must constitute the entire column being moved, rather than an arbitrary number of cards from the bottom of a column.

However, I can't find any other reference to this restriction. In other books of card games I have referenced, they seem to imply simply that arbitrary valid sequences can be moved from one column to another. Can anybody provide a source for the more restrictive version of the rule mentioned in the Wikipedia article?

(My question is hence similar to [this question referring to movement in Klondike](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/15051/klondike-solitaire-moving-partial-sequences-between-columns), but applied to Canfield.)

Comment: http://greenfelt.net/canfield doesn't allow partial-column movements.

Answer (score 3):

[Bicycle cards](http://www.bicyclecards.com/card-games/rule/canfield) lists the more restrictive rule.

> Building
>
> Any movable card or cards (from tableau, reserve, or stock) may be placed only on a card next-higher in rank and of opposite color in the tableau. Example: The  8♥ may be placed on  9♣ or  9♠. An entire pile of the tableau must be moved as a unit.

[Boardgames.about.com](http://boardgames.about.com/od/solitaire/a/canfield.htm) also lists the more restrictive rule.
To move cards from one tableau pile to another, you may only move the entire pile.